# AWK print - replace comma with dot

Tags: printing, awk, format

I run this command line:

```
awk -F "\\t" "NR>=%startcounter%&&NR<=%endcounter% { print """UPDATE tArtikel SET fVKNetto =""" $6 """ WHERE cArtNr = """ $1 """ """;}" fil_a.txt file_b.txt
```

The result is:

```
UPDATE tArtikel SET fVKNetto =27,67 WHERE cArtNr = 60160
```

Is there a easy way in awk to replace the comma, with a dot? 
It should be:

```
UPDATE tArtikel SET fVKNetto =27.67 WHERE cArtNr = 60160
```

I found some solutions, but I would like to make it as short as possible. It would be perfect if the command has not to be completely changed.

Thank you for your help!

Note: I use Winawk

Comment: yes, there is, but you need provide the sample content in `file_a` and `file_b`

Comment: Add `sub(/,/,".",$6);` (with appropriate cmd.exe quoting) before the `print` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This replaces all `,` with `.`

```
awk -F "\\t" "{gsub(/,/,".")} NR>=%startcounter%&&NR<=%endcounter% { print """UPDATE tArtikel SET fVKNetto =""" $6 """ WHERE cArtNr = """ $1 """ """;}" fil_a.txt file_b.txt
```